# How to connect sqlite with mysql database using ionic framework?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, sqlite, local-storage, ionic-framework

now I'm working on hybrid mobile application with SQLite. This application just only retrieve the data from database. The data come from MYSQL database, but I want to store the data into local storage which is SQLite so when the user don't have the internet, they can retrieve the data from local storage. So,is there a way to connect mysql db and sqlite? I have been following the tutorial from [this site](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/deploy-ionic-framework-app-pre-filled-sqlite-db/)

but I do not know how to connect sqlite with mysql db. So,anyone can help me to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using a API that give a response as a JSON and store and access those using ionic local storage
Or you can design a server side code using node js and connect to db